# Invisible Unicode characters inside code comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, unicode

I've recently spent a significant amount of time debugging a problem with a string inside my code.

This produced an error:

```
"root:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/employees?readTimeout=15m‌​"
```

This worked fine:

```
"root:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/employees?readTimeout=15m"
```

As you can see the strings look exactly the same, but when printed out in binary format:

First string:

```
[114 111 111 116 58 112 97 115 115 119 111 114 100 64 116 99 112 40 49 50 55 46 48 46 48 46 49 58 51 51 48 54 41 47 101 109 112 108 111 121 101 101 115 63 114 101 97 100 84 105 109 101 111 117 116 61 49 53 109]
```

Second string:

```
[114 111 111 116 58 112 97 115 115 119 111 114 100 64 116 99 112 40 49 50 55 46 48 46 48 46 49 58 51 51 48 54 41 47 101 109 112 108 111 121 101 101 115 63 114 101 97 100 84 105 109 101 111 117 116 61 49 53 109 226 128 140 226 128 139]
```

The second string happens to have extra two invisible Unicode characters at the end `226 128 140 226 128 139` that represent `ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER` and  `ZERO WIDTH SPACE`.

As it turns out, Stack Overflow inserts invisible characters inside long code comments.

When writing a comment like this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa‌​aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa‌​aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa‌​aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa‌
```

What really happens under the hood is this:

```
[97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 226 128 140 226 128 139 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 226 128 140 226 128 139 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 226 128 140 226 128 139 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 226 128 140]
```

My question is, why does Stack Overflow do this?

Why is inserting invisible characters into code snippets and effectively creating debugging nightmares considered a good solution?

Comment: Yes, this is by design to break up long lines so they wrap.

Comment: See [Occasionally, the Unicode character sequence U+200C U+200B (ZWNJ ZWSP) is inserted into comments](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/170970) for the Meta cross-site dupe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Surely there must be a better way. I didn't see that post, it seems to have a similar example though.

Comment: To be honest, I would much prefer if the break characters were visible, something like <break> instead of inserting invisible magic. Worst thing about it is that once you copy this into your editor, you can't tell it's there. And so your code could bug out at some point in the future and you won't have a clue why that is.

Comment: They could just insert `<wbr>` tags instead though

Comment: @SeinopSys As noted in a comment on the answer to the linked MSE question, `<wbr>` is not supported in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @hvd I would argue that functional effects outrank cosmetic ones by far. Even more so if they only affect users of an outdated and discontinued browser (note that Edge [_does_](https://caniuse.com/#feat=wbr-element) support it).

Comment: @hvd Which is strange, since older versions of IE (5.5-7) supported it.  I guess it was one of the things that was lost in transition when IE8 finally got rid of IE6's broken engine, and they didn't fix it for some reason, even after they finally realised following W3C standards is a good idea.

Comment: @Siguza Look at the answer on the linked MSE question. Without `<wbr>`, the layout gets so messed up, comments overlapping other parts of the page, that this is not just a cosmetic issue but a functional one.

Comment: @JustinTime At the time, `<wbr>` was non-standard.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this seems like a very bad design. Why not introduce some [CSS for IE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23759279/2441442)? The content propery [isn't c&p by FF and Chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/tvw7fyq8/1/). And IE: Shit happens.

Comment: or even better: [`wordbreak:break-all`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, been a while I wanted to make an [user-script](https://pastebin.com/s1vyrH0j) for this. Not to fancy, but does its job...

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt: That was my immediate thought too (with the hyphen, though: `word-break: break-all`). Even works on IE8.

Comment: @Kaiido: Sadly, 'tis true of the current layout for comments. (I'd done a test, but hadn't *quite* faithfully replicated the layout; and if you do, FF breaks.) For me, this is a good enough reason to change the comments layout markup so that rather than getting its width indirectly from the wrapper `div.comments`, it get it via directly-assigned width. The issue of rendering/not rendering the comments controls is solvable. :-)

Comment: @Kaiido: Yeah. That would wrap *all* code-in-comments in the middle of a word. But on a per-comment basis, adding it if the comment contains problematic run of code would work...

Comment: @Kaiido: Unfortunately, adding it to the container would break words in odd places, not just over-long words. Stoopid Firefox. :-) But I think I'm near a solution...

Comment: Here's a feature request to change the design to stop inserting these, with a specific proposal for what to replace it with (which works on Firefox): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295425/stop-inserting-invisible-characters-into-comments

Comment: Copying and pasting text from a comment and expecting it to work in code is the bug here...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan How would you have me copy the valuable information? Split screen a monitor and copy by hand? Or memorise and type it in? We all copy things from the internet. It's the most efficient way of taking a piece of text and placing it in your editor.

Comment: Well, as explained in the comments to the answer, and elsewhere in Meta and help, valuable information should be in the question or answer, not in a comment. Also, I expect people to know what the code (in the comment or anywhere else) does before pasting into any code you expect to work. Therefore, if there are problems with the copied code, you know how it should work, and can easily rewrite it.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. I know very well what the code does, the problem is that since I didn't know where the issue was coming from I spent a long time scratching my head wondering what's happening with the code. This has nothing to do with me not understanding the code or blindly copy pasting stuff from the internet.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: You are missing a vital detail here: Even if you understand what the code does, and could replicate it yourself, you have **no way** to see, that the code you pasted looks different to a compiler/interpreter than to a human reader. The bug really is, that a developer-centric site inserts invisible Unicode voodoo.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - Code which is not meant as an answer, nor valid as an edit, can be very handy in a comment. As user2357112 points out in a comment on Christian Gollhardt's answer below, a commenter could well be using code to help with debugging, effectively asking for clarification, which is one of the *stated purposes* of comments.

Comment: @JohnY If its purpose was truly asking for clarification, then once the question/answer was clarified, the comment (and the code therein) would no longer be needed and should be removed.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Except, the question/answer would never reach that state, because the inquiry to copy the code and respond with the results will never successfully come to a conclusion.

Comment: All, I'm going to bow out of this conversation as apparently people are getting testy about code posted in comments, which I find to be somewhat ridiculous.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: You find it ridiculous to [use comments for their intended purpose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348600/invisible-unicode-characters-inside-code-comments#comment469904_348616)? I must say, I find **that** a tad bit ridiculous.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this is not status-by-design. It's "status-lets-make-comments-better-until-we-remove-the-tables-from-there-but-oh-my-god-tables-are-everywhere-its-a-rabbit-hole-ph'nglui-mglw'nafh-Cthulhu-R'lyeh-wgah'nagl-fhtagn" Disclaimer: I'm responsible for some of that mess. Better writing that than losing my sanity invoking the Ancient One. I'm sure you'll understand

Comment: @Sklivvz: you have my sympathy! But in the end, it was a design nonetheless, however it came about, and not an accident caused by someone tripping over the cable ;-)

Comment: @hvd I mean that it's strange that they removed it in IE8, and strange that they didn't put it back in once they realised standards compliance was a good thing (when they were making IE9, which was when they started to focus on HTML5, CSS3, SVG, XHTML, and JavaScript compliance, I believe); I'd have expected them to add it back in IE9, IE10, or IE11, unless `<wbr>` was added to the HTML5 proposal in 2014.  I didn't mean they started focusing on standards compliance with IE8; I probably should've said "while making IE9" at the end of my comment to clarify this, but I was kinda tired.

Comment: I just find it silly that they supported the tag when it was non-standard, but stopped supporting the tag when it was standard, up until Edge came out.

Comment: @JustinTime "unless `<wbr>` was added to the HTML5 proposal in 2014" -- It was added in 2010, but judging from the IE release dates and the W3 bug to make it standard, that was after IE already had a publicly available version of their browser that no longer supported it. In other words, the moment they stopped supporting it was when it was still non-standard.

Comment: @Siguza "users of an outdated and discontinued browser": I'm not an IE user, but I'm pretty sure it's not outdated. Sure Microsoft introduced Edge as its replacement, but [Internet Explorer 11 will be supported for the life of Windows 7, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsforbusiness/end-of-ie-support) -- that's a pretty long time... As far as I know they only dropped support for versions of IE before 11. Just curious, does IE11 support wbr? (just checked, no it doesn't)

Comment: @jrh Security may be kept up-to-date, but features will remain outdated nevertheless.

Comment: As far as in the question/answer vs. in a comment, if I update an post with additional content from a comment, I'll _usually_ just copy and paste it from the comment. Wouldn't that end up with the same characters in the post as well, or is that not how that works?

Comment: @Siguza ah, I see what you mean. I guess I didn't realize IE was in that intense of a feature freeze.

Comment: @hvd Ah, that makes sense, IE8 came out in 2009.  Still kinda surprising they didn't add it back in for IE9 (released in 2011) or later, though; maybe they were a bit miffed that it was added to the proposal more-or-less right after they took it out, and put it on the back burner out of spite?

Answer (score 146):

I disagree with `[status-bydesign]` (which implies it is not subject to change or correction).

Having invisible characters might be ok for other Stack Exchange Communities, but not for Stack Overflow. Our community uses code snippets on a regular basis.

The problem stated in the question, is reason enough to change something.

Maybe the use of [`word-break:break-all`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/) for code comments would help.

But having a code snippet, which is not working because of additional invisible characters, is [really bad](https://web.archive.org/web/20180122051207/http://codecrap.com/content/6/).

Also remember: HTML is all about Semantics, CSS all about Styling. Changing the semantics to reach a design goal is a second reason against the current implementation.

---

T.J. Crowder created a [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295425/292385), in case you want to support this.

Comment: Putting code in a comment awfully looks like answering the question (or at least part of it) with a comment. So maybe should such comment simply be avoided and replaced by an actual answer, even incomplete.

Comment: @Frédéric not necessary. Sometimes I am asked about some code, but doesn't feel like it should go to the answer/a seperate answer as it is a little bit to localized.

Comment: @Frédéric I don't think that's feasible, I often write follow-up comments that wouldn't be appropriate as a separate answer.

Comment: @Rtsne42, and as an edit? For follow up I frequently do that: first edit, eventually with a dedicated header if I wish it to stand out, then add a comment about the edit. (Especially on my own posts. That is harder to do on other's posts without deviating too much from their intent, but then I rather add a separated full answer, with a summary and credits for the one requiring more details, and adding what is missing.)

Comment: @Frédéric True, I was thinking more in terms of giving follow up comments under someone else's answer. Let's say you come across an answer that has an outdated code snippet and you'd like to post a comment to clarify how the code should look. You can't really make a separate answer out of that, and you can't really edit someone's answer directly. The only thing you can do is add a comment with code inside it.

Comment: If the code is good enough to be copied, then it probably should be posted **as an answer** instead. Comments are **not** meant to be permanent, they are disposable by their very nature.

Comment: And inserting the zero-width characters is certainly by design; the site developers explicitly put them in there. It's not a bug, it is a specific feature that was crafted to work this way. It's fine to disagree with wether or not it's a good idea to do it this way, but disagreeing with the status is a little.. silly, because that implies that the feature was put in by accident instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: status-bydesign "indicates that the specified behavior is intentional and **not subject to change or correction**", so we're going to disagree with that all we want. The design is actively harmful to user requirements. The design has a bug. We're not going to complain any less about a bug simply because the design says it should be that way.

Comment: @user2357112 what is actively harmful is copying and pasting stuff from *comments* and/or *quotes*.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: As opposed to what, retyping it? If someone leaves me a comment saying that I should show them the output of `System.out.println(transactionAwarePersistenceManagerFactoryProxy.getTargetPersistenceManagerFactory())` to help them debug my code, am I wrong to copy-paste that instead of retyping? Retyping is a source of endless bugs and something to be avoided wherever possible. Working copy-paste functionality is crucial.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I believe it works when copying from code snippets though. Tbh I'm a bit divided, the specific case of having that particular snippet, in your comment, *does* feel like it should be copyable, however I can't help but agree that comments should not be answers.

Comment: If the answer is really "don't put long lines of code in comments", then don't allow them to be posted instead of poisoning them with invisible characters.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - No one is saying that comments should be answers. But the use-case pointed out by user2357112 is precisely one of the *intended* uses for comments; namely, asking for clarification. Thus, the invisible characters are actively harming the intended use of comments. (And as noted in T.J. Crowder's feature request, they are also not even achieving the desired goal.)

Comment: Not sure why you start with "I disagree with [tag:status-bydesign]".  It is status-bydesign.  You disagree with the implementation, not that it is designed this way.

Comment: @Joe, I disagree with status-bydesign, which means it is not subject to change or correction

Comment: The design is that it should wrap, the implementation is by adding hidden characters. You say you disagree with the idea that it should wrap?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I said I disagree with the current implementation. I never said it should not wrap. To summary, status-bydesign is the same for me, as the current implementation is correct.

Comment: @Christian: _"Sometimes I am asked about some code, but doesn't feel like it should go to the answer/a seperate answer as it is a little bit to localized."_ Then find a chatroom. Comments are not for this. You are deliberately bypassing the entire peer review system for technical suggestions and information.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: Turns out the invisible unicode crap happens in chat, too! Not with code blocks in chat, but the correct way to use code blocks in chat is weird and arcane enough that plenty of people are going to use backticks instead.